# Why this method is called twice and at the first time the return doesn't work?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, amf

A flash application uses AMF message format to call the method SyncAddressBook (c#),and in this method ,it calls other two WebApis using HttpWebRequest (post and get ).

But only when calling WebApi (the method SyncAddressBook ), the method can return to flash well, when  calling WebApi (the method SyncAddressBook ), the method SyncAddressBook can not return to the one which called it (i didnot write this method here) ,instead, it return itself. and for the second time, the method SyncAddressBook returned with error to flash .

here is the method (I omit something)

```
    public AMFGreetoAddressBookResult SyncAddressBook(AMFGreetoLogin loginArgs, AMFGreetoAddressBook addressBook)
    {
             var result = new ........
            this.PostReceiversGroups(addressBook, accessKey);
            this.GetReceivers(accessKey, out receivers);
             result.ResultCode = true;
            return result;
     }


    private Boolean PostReceiversGroups(AMFGreetoAddressBook addressBook, string accessKey)
    {
        Uri theUri = new Uri(athenaSiteUrl + "/api/receivers");
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(theUri);
        httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(AuthenticationServiceCodeHeaderKey, AddressServiceAccessCode);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(uthenticationServiceAccessKeyHeaderKey, AddressServiceAccessKey);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(AuthenticationUserAccessKey, accessKey);
        httpWebRequest.Host = theUri.Host;

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string json = serializer.Serialize(addressBook);
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(json);
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        try
        {
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Account acc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("住所管理サービスの更新処理でエラーが発生しました。[PostReceiversGroups] :" + e);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private Boolean GetReceivers(string accessKey, out AMFGreetoReceiver[] receivers)
    {
        Uri theUri = new Uri(athenaSiteUrl + "/api/receivers");
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(theUri);
        httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(AuthenticationServiceCodeHeaderKey, AddressServiceAccessCode);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(uthenticationServiceAccessKeyHeaderKey, AddressServiceAccessKey);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(AuthenticationUserAccessKey, accessKey);
        httpWebRequest.Host = theUri.Host;

        receivers = null;
        try
        {
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                receivers = ser.Deserialize<AMFGreetoReceiver[]>(result);
                streamReader.Close();
                httpResponse.Close();
            }              
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Receivers取得処理でエラーが発生しました。[GetReceivers] :" + e);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What does _"the first "return" doesnot work, and the method is called twice"_ mean exactly?

Comment: it means, when the SyncAddressBook called GetReceivers,and then when SyncAddressBook  goes to the last line → return result;　it didnot return to the method which called SyncAddressBook ,instead, it went to itself(SyncAddressBook), it looks like that the method "SyncAddressBook is called twice".and when i comment out the GetReceivers method, it works fine.(the last line → return result return to the method which called SyncAddressBook well)

Comment: the differens between method PostReceiversGroups and GetReceivers is one uses POST and one uses GET in their body so i wonder if the httpWebRequest get conflicted with something 
that associated with Flash,(maybe the AMF message call)

Comment: It might help if you give more context into how `SyncAddressBook` is being called.  The description of 'it went to itself' is a little vague.  Did execution go to another method inside the class?  If calls to `GetReceivers` take time to complete, does the object invoking `SyncAddressBook` correctly handle that (in other words, does it wait for the request to fully complete)?

Comment: JasonZ,thank you for your explanation and your time. I find the problem may be in anywhere else, maybe the return type (Object) does not match the type definited in ActionScript(AMF),so the method can not return.